# How to tell browser to load the page returned from jQuery $.get

Tags: jquery, node.js

My server app is returning an HTML page to the following jQuery $.get at the client, but I don't know how to tell jQuery to have the browser load this page. This seems to be the simplest of all examples, but I could not find the answer.

```
$.get(url, function (data) { 
    // data = new HTML page to be loaded by browser
});
```

Comment: what is data contains whole html or just page name (a.html)

Comment: The whole HTML data

Comment: @Janaka The whole HTML data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="container"></div>

$.get(url, function (data) { 
   $('#container').load(data.filename);
   // or
   $('#container').html(data);
   // or
  window.location.href = data.filename;
});
```

Comment: @Janaja This just adds the 'data' to the 'container' id. I need the whole page loaded that is contained in 'data'.

Comment: $('body').html(data);

Comment: That WORKED!!  Thanks so, so much.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just a part of your page to get replaced you can create a wrapper:

```
 <div id="wrapper">
 </div>
```

And then replace the content with `jQuery`:

```
 $.get(url, function (data) { 
    // data = new HTML page to be loaded by browser
    $('#wrapper').html(responseData);
 });
```

UPDATE:

If you want the whole page to be replace use the same method but with document itself like this:

```
$('body').replaceWith(data);
```

Comment: This just adds the 'data' to the 'wrapper' div id (which I already have as my top level 'div'. I need the whole page loaded that is contained in 'data'.

Comment: It almost worked. The 'replaceWith' replaced the page, but it was not loaded. I need it loaded by the browser

Comment: if it get's loaded by browser you cannot set it by code. It has to come from server @P.Nuzum